# Symfony - Sylius : Symfony VarDumper server no output inside console

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony5, sylius, symfony6

#### Context

I'm trying to use the Symfony VarDumper server to debug controller calls from an external API.
I'm a using Sylius 1.11 : the Symfony VarDumper is already as a core dependencies of the framework.

I have followed all the explanations here :

- https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/components/var_dumper.html
- https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-vardumper-server

Here is my `debug.yaml` :

```yaml
#config/packages/debug.yaml

debug:
    dump_destination: "tcp://%env(VAR_DUMPER_SERVER)%"
```

Then, I'm running the command to run the Symfony webserver : `symfony server:start --no-tls` and the one for the VarDumper webserver : `symfony console server:dump`

Here is the output of the VarDumper webserver :
[image]

Here is my controller with a `dump` instruction inside :

```php
<?php
class AvailabilityAction extends AbstractController
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        dump('hellofriend');

        return new JsonResponse([
            "sessions" => [
                [
                    "startTimeLocal" => '2022-12-10 10:00:00',
                    "endTimeLocal" => '2022-12-10 12:00:00',
                    "seats" => 200,
                    "seatsAvailable" => 200
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here the ouput of the curl command to test the route :
[image]

#### Issue

As we can see on the following picture, we can't see the output of the `dump` command. This is catch by the VarDumper webserver.. this is almost perfect.. but the output of the `dump` command not showing inside the VarDumper webserver output

[image]